# Prove a function is periodic if it satisfies certain criteria

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, periodic-functions

Excuse me if the notation below is wrong in some way, I do not have any special background and learn Math alone.

What i'm investigating now is:

> Given a function $f(x)$ prove that it is periodic if $ \{ \exists\; T\ne 0 : \forall x \in D(f), \; x+T \in D(f), \; x-T \in D(f) \; \text{and} \ P \; \text{is true}\implies f(x-T) = f(x+T) \}$ where $P$ is one of the following statements:
>   $$ 
> f(x+T) = -f(x) \label{eq:1} \\ 
> f(x+T) = {1\over{f(x)}} \\
> f(x+T) = {{f(x) + a}\over{b\cdot f(x)-1}}\\
> f(x+T) = {1 \over {1-f(x)}}
> $$

**Case 1:**

$$
f(x+T) = -f(x) \iff f(x) = -f(x-T) \\
f(x) = -f(x-T) \iff -f(x) = f(x-T)
$$

Therefore $f(x) = f(x) \iff f(x+T) = f(x-T)$, and its period is $2T$

**Case 2:**

$$
f(x+T) = {1\over f(x)} \iff f(x) = {1\over f(x-T)} \\
{{1\over f(x)} = {1 \over f(x)}} \iff f(x+T) = f(x-T)
$$

**Case 3:**
$$
f(x+T) = {{f(x)+ a}\over b\cdot f(x)-1} \iff f(x)={{f(x-T)+a} \over {b\cdot f(x-T) -1}} \\
f(x)(b\cdot f(x-T)-1) = f(x-T) + a \\
f(x)(b\cdot f(x-T)-1) - f(x-T) = a \\
b\cdot f(x) f(x-T) - f(x) - f(x-T) = a \\
b\cdot f(x) f(x-T) - f(x-T) = f(x) + a \\
f(x-T) (b\cdot f(x)  - 1) = f(x) + a \\
f(x-T) = { {f(x) + a} \over {b\cdot f(x)  - 1} }\\
f(x-T) = f(x+T)
$$

**Case 4:**

I couldn't untangle this one, what steps should I take to prove condition from case 4 makes a function periodic? I'm also interested whether the solution for the first 3 ones even makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For case 4, write out $f(x+3T)$ in terms of $f(x)$;
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x+3T)&=&\frac{1}{1-f(x+2T)}
=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-f(x+T)}}
=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-f(x)}}}\\
&=&\frac{1}{1-\frac{1-f(x)}{1-f(x)-1}}
=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1-f(x)}{f(x)}}
=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{f(x)}-1}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}=f(x).
\end{eqnarray*}

For the other three cases your reasoning is fine, but be careful with claims about a 'minimal period'. Generally all you can say is that the function $f$ is periodic with a period $2T$. It might also be periodic with other periods (for example period $T$, or $f$ could be constant). For case 3 an intermediate step for how you found the expression for $f(x-T)$ might also be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! As for case 3, I've printed it with a mistake, thanks for spotting. fixed the OP